Firebase - Not receiving the Facebook Oauth 2.0 popup consent form, only signed in automatically
so I've had this problem for a while. If you take a look at my screenshot, you'll notice I dont recieve any identifier and also the email of the user, I am suspecting its because the consent popup to sign in with Facebook never displays, its like its bypassed and directly signs in the user.
I have configured the settings perfect at https://developers.facebook.com/ and in Firebase console with the App ID, secret and handler so the problem is not there.
The issue is my code:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    const app = firebase.app();
    console.log(app);
  });
  
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: 'placeholder',
      autoLogAppEvents: true,
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v13.0',
    });
  
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };
  
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  function showWarningMessage(message) {
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'warning',
        title: 'Varning',
        text: message,
        confirmButtonColor: '#2e4873',
        confirmButtonText: 'OK'
    });
}
  
  function facebookLogin() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('flexCheckDefault');
    if (checkbox && !checkbox.checked) {
        showWarningMessage("Try again.");

        return;
    }
  
    const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('email');
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('User is logged in and granted some permissions.');
            
            firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
                .then((result) => {
                    const user = result.user;
                    
                    // Store additional user data in Firestore
                    const db = firebase.firestore();
                    db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({
                        uid: user.uid,
                        displayName: user.displayName,
                        email: user.email,// This is always null or empty.
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log("User data successfully written to Firestore!");

                        sessionStorage.setItem('notificationTime', new Date().toISOString());
                        
                        // Redirect to home page
                        window.location.href = "../pages/home.html";
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error("Error writing user data to Firestore: ", error);
                    });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, { scope: 'public_profile,email' });
  }



Anyone got a clew?
